# Why is my query not giving results?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have this query to show upcoming competitions:

```
$today = strtotime(date( 'Y-m-d' ));
 $args = array(
     'post_type'=>array('posts', 'competition'),
     );
 query_posts($args);
```

It worked, but I wanted show only not ended ones, so I added this:

```
$today = strtotime(date( 'Y-m-d' ));
 $args = array(
     'post_type'=>array('posts', 'competition'),
     'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'competition-end-date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
       )
     );
 query_posts($args);
```

I needed this, because I want to show only those which are not ended. Can someone say why it's not giving me results?

Comment: what is the content of any `meta_value` with the `meta_key` `competition-end-date` in the table `[prefix]_postmeta`? maybe it cannot interpreted like a date?

Comment: For timestamps, `type` should be `TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments, It has been fixed by replacing 'type' => 'DATE' with 'type' => 'NUMERIC' I hope this will be helpfull. I adding link where I finded my answer https://gist.github.com/billerickson/3698476#file-gistfile1-php